# Computed property, filters and updates to DOM

Tags: ractivejs

I have a computed property with a lot of elements.
Based on user input, I need to filter out some of the elements on which it's based.

```
[
    {name:'hal',    display: false},
    {name:'john',   display: true },
    {name:'jack',   display: false},
    {name:'george', display: true },
    {name:'tom',    display: false},
    {name:'rick',   display: false},
    {name:'paul',   display: true },
    {name:'ringo',  display: true },
]
```

In my example, I want to be able to filter out elements that have `display:false` at will.

What happens is that, due to the efficency of how Ractive reacts to data changes, only specific changes get performed on the DOM, triggering unwanted transitions.

**A fiddle is worth a thousand words:** http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/4/ (edited, [see old version](http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/2/))

If you click the toggle button, you'll notice that a transition gets performed on the computed elements on the left.

I believe this happens because Ractive, rather than updating the whole `<li>....</li>` tag, updates just the specific parts that should be affected. In this specific case: name and class.

```
<li class="animateme animateme-{{display}}">{{name}}</li>
```

What I'd like to do is:

- keep using computed properties
- rebuild the whole `<li>` on data change (basically, giving up some of Ractive's efficency)

Any tip on how I can do that?

(it's entirely possibile that I'm approaching this issue in the wrong way, if so, please let me know)

---

edit:

**tl;dr.** visual transition should trigger when any of the 'display' property gets modified (i.e. ), not when 'display:false' elements are being filtered out.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/4/

Comment: You want the functionality of the right side, right?  Where there's no slow animation effect?

Comment: exactly. I don't want to show any transition, because no 'display' property is actually being changed.

Comment: So is this what you're going for?  http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/3/

Comment: From a visual perspective, yes. I still need transitions to be on though (imagine you could actually change 'display' property of elements at runtime, with a switch-like animation, by clicking on people's name).


Basically: visual transition should happen when I'm changing the 'display' property, but not when 'display:false' elements are being filtered out.

Comment: Updated fiddle to add a simple "switch" like interaction. http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/5/ for examples below.

I actually think the inline filtered example is the better approach, you can move the logic into a function if it becomes complicated:

```
{{#if show(this) }} ... {{/if}}

...

data: {
    show ( item ) {
        const active = this.get( 'active' );
        return active !== true || item.display;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to use an `ractive.observe` and a `ractive.merge` to achieve the same effect as a computed property, but with identity aware DOM node semantics:

```
this.observe('active', active => {
    const entries = this.get('entries');
    const merge = active ? entries.filter( entry => entry.display ) : entries;
    this.merge( 'filtered', merge );
});
```

Note that this highlights the fact that ractive does not track changes between identical object references in different arrays (unless using magic mode), a fact "hidden" by the recomputation of `filteredElements` that was occurring on each data change in your original example.

If you need this behavior you can set up observers to map between the arrays:

```
    this.observe('filtered.*.display', ( display, o, k, index ) => {
        this.update('entries.'+index+'.display' );
    });
    this.observe('entries.*.display', ( display, o, k, index ) => {
        this.update('filtered.'+index+'.display' );
    });
```

Or in next version of ractive (`0.8`) you could possibly use the link method.

EDIT: One more option I thought of is to disable transitions when the filter changes. See http://jsfiddle.net/7kubqbba/6/:

```
    <li on-click="changeDisplay:{{i}},{{display}}" class="animateme animateme-{{display}} {{#if noTransition}}noTransition{{/if}}">{{name}}</li>

    // in component:
    self.observe('filteredElements', (n, o) => {
        if ( n!==o ) {
            this.set( 'noTransition', true );
        }
    })

    self.observe('filteredElements', (n, o) => {
        setTimeout( () => this.set( 'noTransition', false ) );
    }, { defer: true });
```